# Working with simpleDateFormat in other country in Android

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I was working with **SimpleDateFormat** in android to parse Date ,below is my code. the problem that i'm facing is that my code was working properly from last 3 month when the user was of **India** but now a guy from **Poland** has started using this and he is getting null pointer exception on last line of if loop for the same application. I think the problem is with Indian time and other country's time.

entered Date was :22-Jan-1970

```
    if (!enteredDate.equals("")) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = sdf.parse(enteredDate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            String dob = sdf.format(date);
}
```

and i can't even check it since i'm in India hence i'm not getting that exception, so can anybody help me to solve this problem.
Any Help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: can you give us one of the problematic enteredDate values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's problem with Locale. 
In Polish we get this String when parsed your time:
`22-sty-1970`.

Try parse with English locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: yup Locale.ENGLISH was the missing part now it's working properly. Thanks A Lot.